# How to create a histogram in R with range table class?

Tags: r

Help me, please! I'm a beginner student in statistics and I have to create a histogram of this table (duration in hours x number of lamps):

```
0-100: 82
100-200: 71
200-300: 68
300-400: 56
400-500: 43
500-800: 15
```

Comment: You may need a bar plot i.e. if it s a `table` object just do `barplot(yourtable)`

Answer (score 0):

Akrun's right; this data is already summarized so you can just make a bar plot.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# set up our data frame, making the range into a factor for ordering
df <- tribble(~range, ~count,
"0-100", 82,
"100-200", 71,
"200-300", 68,
"300-400", 56,
"400-500", 43,
"500-800", 15) %>%
  mutate(range = factor(range))

# make a bar plot
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=range, y = count), width = 1)
```

Comment: Awesome! If it helped, please don't forget to mark the answer correct :)

Comment: I tried, but the platform said "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." haha